# Mocks; assigning delegates using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

### Currently

I'm using [`Moq`](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Methods) to create a handful of mock objects; thus far everything is working nicely. Currently to 'assign' a delegate using Moq I'm doing

```
var someMock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
someMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(this.DoSomething)
```

Where `this.DoSomething` is a method accepting an `int` parameter; fundamentally it's the same structure as `x.DoSomething` on the `ISomeInterface`.

### Question

Is it possible to simply assign a delegate, without the neeed for specifying all of its parameters, i.e. **not using** `It.IsAny<int>()`? Ideally something like this:

```
var someMock = new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
someMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething).Returns(this.DoSomething)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. That's not a "shortcoming" of Moq - C# doesn't support it.

Some background:

Let's assume `ISomeInterface` is declared as follows:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void Foo(int a, int b);
}
```

That would mean that the parameter of the `Setup` method would have to be a `Func<ISomeInterface, Action<int, int>>`.
The problem now is that the `Setup` method would have to be defined in a generic way, because your method could have any type of parameters:

```
Setup<T1, T2>(Func<T, Action<T1, T2>> param)
```

`T` is the generic type from the Mock class, `T1` and `T2` are the parameters of the method.

Calling this method however will result in a compiler error:

> The type arguments for method `Mock.Setup<T1, T2>(System.Func<UserQuery.ISomeInterface,System.Action<T1,T2>>)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

To make it work, you would need to call it like this:

```
someMock.Setup<int, int>(x => x.DoSomething)
```

or like this:

```
someMock.Setup(x => (Action<int, int>)x.DoSomething);
```

In both cases, you would have to specify the type of the parameters, just as you do it now already.

As to why you get the compiler error:

`x.DoSomething` is a method group. There exists an implicit conversion to `Action<int, int>`.
However, for this implicit conversion to be executed, the compiler needs to know the types of `T1` and `T2`. But those types can only be inferred after the conversion took place.
Those two steps depend on each other and that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I assumed the types would automatically be inferred from the methods, my mistake. Would it be possible to do something like this: `someMock.Setup<int, int>(x => x.DoSomething).Returns(this.DoSomething)`?

Comment: @Richard: That's possible in C#, yes. But it would require the authors of Moq to provide such a method - which they currently don't as far as I know.

Comment: cool thanks. I'll consider extension methods on `Moq` or maybe using a wrapper. Thanks again.